# Zoom - Problems with sound in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have some weird issues with Zoom in Ubuntu 20.04. **Every time** I join a meeting and select "Join with my Computer Audio", Zoom volume starts at 10%:

[image]

The second problem is weirder. It happens when I am in a meeting created by a specific colleague of mine (and only him!): when someone enters or leaves the room, Zoom's volume falls to 0%. I must manually changing again. This doesn't happen with anyone else, nor does it happen to the other participants of the meeting. It's only me.

I have Zoom 5.5.4 for Linux. Any ideas what might be the problem? Feels like a local issue. Some odd configuration.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I simply suggest thing you can try to diagnose or get rid of it.
1) Update your Zoom version (there is at least 5.6.1 available) and have your friend do the same.
2) Try with meetings created by other people.
3) In your settings, uncheck "Automatically adjust microphone volume" and set "Suppress background noise" to Low.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Thanks. Updated and joined another meeting by my friend and same problem. Changed settings as suggested and same. When someone enters, I get muted.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue it automatically adjusts the zoom mic volume. I thought it was an OS issue. However, it was from the zoom app.
There is an option called "Automatically adjust microphone volume" under settings > Audio > Microphone.
That solved my issue you can just check that setting.

[image]

Comment: I had difficulty with this, until I realised that you don't get access to the settings unless you sign in. So I had to create an account _just_ to be able to change the settings on my local app.

Answer (score 3):

Most recent call softwares do have some automatic volume levelling. Look after volume or device options in Zoom.

It may also be a pulseaudio/pavucontrol issue, but it's far less likely considering that Zoom is an Electron "app".
Web "apps" are known to be far more buggy than real ones, an infamous example would be Discord which is also known for the same issues you have.

Other than that, you may try to install Zoom from another place and see if it fix things, like from a flatpak.
How to use flatpak with a GUI (`gnome-software` aka "Software"): https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks. I installed the latest version and problem remains. Audio settings seem to change nothing. (See comment to question).

Comment: You mean the latest version from flathub or ? If yes, that's odd since no configuration files would have been reused. Have you also checked if there's an auto volume or some settings like that ? If yes again, then it's a pulseaudio issue, but I wonder how it could have kept the same settings for two fully different versions.

Comment: I didn't use the flatpak (never heard of it). Just installed manually from website. I didn't remove config files though (did `sudo apt remove` rather than `sudo apt purge`, as I don't want to reconfigure local account.

Comment: good ole electron

Comment: @luchonacho : Please try Zoom's flatpak version to confirm if it's a Zoom issue or a pulseaudio/pavucontrol one.

Comment: It works! Thanks! So does that mean it is a pulseaudio issue? How can I debut it further?

Comment: It now mostly looks like a Zoom issue. Flatpak is a powerful way to install softwares and will prevent you many issues, always try to find your software there first before going to your Linux's repository as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the other answers helped.

Finally, changing *Zoom background noise removal* in Zoom (*Settings* --> *Audio*) from "Auto" to "Low" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I couldn't hear anything in Zoom, I also checked the PulseAudio per-application levels but Zoom was apparently turned up.

It took my quite a while to find this, but I eventually realised that the mute/unmute button actually has an embedded menu which allows you to select the output device. And in my case it had picked a wrong output device so just changing device fixed the problem for me.

[image]